# fatal: bad revision 'bc3c10d5ba0428b17e7da14e80339b8a621a067d

Tags: git, github, webstorm, github-for-windows

Each time I attempt to commit to my GIT repo using WebStorm I get the following

```
fatal: bad revision 'bc3c10d5ba0428b17e7da14e80339b8a621a067d:registration/age/age-olp.component.ts'
```

For each file that an attempt to commit is made the revision is the same but the file name changes.

There are no other `.git` repo in my application folder.
I have looked at some help in stack but none helps.

Is there a way to correct this? I can't remember doing anything unusual.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, start first to:

- switch to command line
- make sure you are using the latest Git 2.13
- check `git status` to see if your repo is correctly checked out to a valid branch

Also try and see if the issue persists on a new clone of the same repo (cloned in a different folder): if you can make a commit there, chances are you will be able to report your work from your defective local repo to that new one, and push from the new cloned repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had got such error when file was included to the `.gitignore` file.